# ChildProcess::LaunchError for browsermob proxy server start

Tags: ruby, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use browsermob proxy in my Selenium tests. Hence I wrote following code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new 'E:\browsermob\browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-8'
server.start
```

But when I run above script, it results into `ChildProcess::LaunchError` :

```
ChildProcess::LaunchError: Unknown error (Windows says "The operation completed successfully.", but it did not.)
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.9/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:87:in `create_process'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.9/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:34:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.9/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:63:in `launch_process'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.9/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:72:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob/proxy/server.rb:27:in `start'
    from (irb):9
    from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced with the same issue and it was hard to figure out from the documentation here to understand that path to browsermob-proxy server should also include executable.

In your case the code should be the next:

require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new "E:\browsermob\browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-8\browsermob-proxy"
server.start

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Mako! But in the path, I had to mention the path of bat file with extension like `E:\browsermob\browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-8\browsermob-proxy.bat`